# HowTo: Pass props to page defined styled component?

Tags: css, styled-components

So I'm having an issue dynamically passing the background colour of a button to an styled component I have defined. If I import the styled component as follows:

```html
import styled from 'styled-components';

const CartQuantityButton = styled.button`
    background: ${props => props.background};
    ...
`;

export default CartQuantityButton;
```

Mycomponent .js

```html
import CartQuantityButton from './styles/CartQuantityButton';

return (
    <CartItemStyles>
        <Mutation 
            mutation={UPDATE_CART_ITEM_MUTATION} 
            variables={this.state}
        >
            {(updateCartItem, { loading, error }) => {
            return (
                <Form2>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellPadding="0"> 
                    <tr>
                        <td><CartQuantityButton background={loading ? 'grey' : 'red'} type="submit">Updat{loading ? 'ing' : 'e'}</CartQuantityButton></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </Form2>
            )
            }}
        </Mutation>
  </CartItemStyles>
)
```

everything works as expected, the background colour switches from red to grey. But if I define the styled component as part of MyComponent.js, as follows:

```html
const Form2 = styled.form`
  ...
  button,
  input[type='submit'] {
    background: ${props => props.background};
  }
`;

return (
    <CartItemStyles>
        <Mutation 
            mutation={UPDATE_CART_ITEM_MUTATION} 
            variables={this.state}
        >
            {(updateCartItem, { loading, error }) => {
            return (
                <Form2>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellPadding="0"> 
                    <tr>
                        <td><button background={loading ? 'grey' : 'red'} type="submit">Updat{loading ? 'ing' : 'e'}</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </Form2>
            )
            }}
        </Mutation>
  </CartItemStyles>
)
```

the background colour of the `<button/>` isn't picked up. What am I overlooking here?

Comment: add background={loading ? 'grey' : 'red'} on <Form2> as props and check

Comment: @Abhineet Yep, that worked. Although I must say I think it's far more readable specifying the background on the actual button. Many thanks.